# Why - in Java 1.8 - is Function<V,R> used and not Function<R,V>?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, java-8

The order  seems odd because in regular Java the return type is always specified first.  As in:

```
public static double sum(Iterable<Number> nums) { ... }
```

Why then, in the Function and BiFunction classes has the choice been made to specify them the other way around?  As in:

```
interface Function<T,R>
interface BiFunction<T,U,R>
```

I'm not asking here for opinions as to which is better, but specifically:

a) Is there any technical or other (non-stylistic) benefit in preferring one order over the other?  Or is it an arbitrary choice?

b) Is anyone aware of any documented explanation, or any stated reason from an authoritative source, why one was chosen over the other?

Aside: the order seems even more odd if extended to higher arities.  For example, a hypothetical QuadFunction:

```
interface QuadFunction<A,B,C,D,R> { ... }
```

(At the time of writing the highest arity in the library is 2 - i.e. BiFunction.)

See: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: What do you mean "the other way around"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @arshajii He's talking about `QuadFunction<R, A, B, C, D>` (instead of `QuadFunction<A, B, C, D, R>`) to mirror `R foo(A a, B b, C c, D d) { ... }`

Comment: In part, I'm asking because I work with a pre-1.8 library that has these interfaces (or rather equivalents) the 'other way around'.

Comment: Its to be consistent with prior existing notation.

The mathematically integer division function extended into the rational numbers:
(\): I x I -> Q

Functional programming version of the above
division :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)

or 

division :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer

Comment: My guess is that it as simple as 'V' for value and 'R' for result. I am sure there are more profound answers ... Usually I put T as an input and R as an output ('T' for type and again 'R' for result.)

Comment: I think they just used it because it's done in C# like that.

Comment: `Function<T,R>` conforms to `Map<K,V>` as a function maps values of `T` to values of `R`.

Comment: We actually tried it both ways during the evolution of the library.  People *overwhelmingly hated* `Function<R,T>`.  We surmised that this was because they wanted to read it as "Function from T to R" rather than "Function returning R taking argument T".

Comment: @Brian Thanks - interesting to know.  I've now changed our in-house library to be consistent with the Java 1.8 interfaces (in preparation for a switch to 1.8).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is to be consistent with prior existing notation.

The mathematical integer division function extended into the rational numbers:

```
(\): I x I -> Q
```

Functional programming version of the above (like Haskell, Ocaml)

```
division :: Integer -> (Integer -> Rational)

or

division :: Integer -> Integer -> Rational
```

All three say "the division function takes two integers and returns a rational number". It is backwards, in a functional paradigm, to say your returns first. C has taught us to say "we return a rational number in the division function, which takes two integers" (ex float division(int a, int b){}).

In Java, your return type is on the left of methods because Java wants to look like C. The designers of C thought "int main(int argv, char *argv[])" looked better than "main(int argv, char *argv[]) int". When writing code, atleast for me, I more often than not know what a method will return before I know what it will need. (edit 1: and we write lines like String s=removeSpaces(textLine), so the return on the left matches the variable on the left)

In C#, [func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) looks the same way as the Java 8 Function.

Comment: Okay.  Makes sense.  Also, I agree that I usually know what I want to return before I'm sure what I need to pass (when writing a function).  But - *putting other arguments aside* - isn't that an argument for putting the return value first, not last?  (Not that I mean to argue against the established convention.)

Comment: @Paul check Andrey Chaschev's answer. In functional & functional-like programming, you chain functions quite often. Using C# or Ocaml, you may see one-liners like createList(...).filter(....).trimToSize(....), where data flows 'to the right'.

In imperative programming, usually we capture values on the left (int i = getUserID(username)) then will do something with the captured value. In fact, chaining methods is considered bad practice in imperative languages!

Comment: I think the killer argument (that I also made in my answer) is that it is the established notation in mathematics and functional programming. Java programmers are quite new to the realm where  `void doSomething()` is useless, meaningless and frowned upon, hence they better learn the prior conventions with regards to functions.

Comment: I think the killer argument is that if Java would have been started in Egypt, you would have lambda arrows pointing left. No jokes here!

Comment: @AndreyChaschev You're serious? Egypt mathematicians write something like "let f : B <- A be a function to Bs from As ..."?

Comment: @Ingo We kinda see that in purer functional languages like Haskell with nomads.

Comment: @Ingo Wiki: [Modern Arabic mathematical notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Arabic_mathematical_notation). Function definition example is missing there, but there are many other samples which leave no chances to regular arrows - i.e. `lim` arrows.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev And here I thought Math notation was standardized, a "universal language".

Comment: @John Yeah, this was quite a surprise for me too.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that it's more intuitive for method chaining which might be a typical use case for lambdas, i.e.

```
IntStream.range(1, 10).map(Ints::random).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
```

So, method sequense here reads left to right and lambdas go left to right. So why not having the type params go left to right?

Escalating this a bit further - the reason might be that the English language reads left to right. :-)

**UPDATE**

I was very surprised to find out that this is something which takes place for [maths modern arabic notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Arabic_mathematical_notation):

**Latin complex numbers**

[image: latin complex numbers]

**Arabic complex numbers**

[image: arabic complex numbers]

In this example arabic notation in every char mirrors latin. One can track this by the angle sign and *i* (imagenary unit) char - in both cases it has a dot. In the linked wiki article there is also an example of a reversed `lim` arrow (compared to Java 8 lamda's arrow direction). This could mean that arabic Java, if it was ever developed, would look a bit differently. :-)

Disclaimer: I have background in maths, but I had no idea of the arabic notation when I was answering this question.

Comment: I'm surprised people didn't up-vote your answer (0 as I posted this). You actually gave the best and most concise answer.

Answer (score 4):

In ordinary procedural and OO programming, functions/methods generally take a list of parameters and return some result:

```
int max(int num1, int num2)
```

When rewriting function signatures as callback-based (such as for parallel or asynchronous processing), it has been a longstanding practice to convert the signature by appending the return callback as the last parameter:

```
void maxAsync(int num1, int num2, Callback<int> callback) // pseudo-Java
```

A current example of this pattern can be found in [GWT RPC processing](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).

This style originated in the Lisp style of languages with the so-called [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), where functions are chained by passing a function *to* a function as a parameter. Since in Lisp arguments are evaluated left-to-right, the function that's consuming the values needs to be at the end of the list. This arrangement has been adopted by imperative languages for continuity and because it's been traditional to tack on additional optional parameters (boolean flags and the like) at the end of the parameter list.

Answer (score 4):

It is the explicit intent to make it more convenient to program in a functional style in Java. Now, in mathematics, a function is generally written like

```
f: A -> B
```

(i.e., a function from As to Bs). This corresponds also to the notation in functional languages, Scala and already existing functional libraries for Java.

In other words: it is just the right thing.

Note that a functional interface is not a method and a method is not a functional interface, hence it is not clear what the syntax of the former has to do with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion: to look the same way as `Function` in guava does. Having the order the other way around would cause a lot of confusion I guess.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html

Comment: Only if you use Guava.  ;-)  Isn't consistency with the underlying language more important?

Comment: Could at least have played a role - Java 8 seems to take some hints from Guava, e.g. the Optional class (which in turn might be inspired by some other API?).

Comment: @shutefan I'd venture that Optional is rather taken directly from the Maybe monad from haskell, just with a different name...